# How to store emoji characters in DB2 database?

Tags: sql, database, db2, emoji

I have an application that it's storing tweets in a DB2 database, and need to retrieve them in some moments. I'm having troubles showing text string with emojis inside (some emojis loose the format).

I've been reading different answers in internet, but most are for MySQL (switch from utf8 to utf8mb4), but nothing for DB2...

Is there any way to do something like the following in DB2 databases?

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Thanks too much

Answer (score 4):

You can use Unicode constants like this in a Db2 Unicode database

```
$ db2 "values U&'\+01F600'"

1   
----
   

  1 record(s) selected.
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000731.html

> U& followed by a sequence of characters that starts and ends with a string delimiter and that is optionally followed by the UESCAPE clause. This form of a character string constant is also called a Unicode string constant.
>
> A character can be expressed by either its typographical character (glyph) or its Unicode code point. The code point of a Unicode character ranges from X'000000' to X'10FFFF'.
>
> To express a Unicode character through its code point, use the Unicode escape character followed by 4 hexadecimal digits, or the Unicode escape character followed by a plus sign (+) and 6 hexadecimal digits. The default Unicode escape character is the reverse solidus ()

or you can use UTF-8 HEX values if you prefer

```
db2 "values x'F09F9880'"

1   
----
   

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you clarify what is the issue? With UTF-8 database there is no issues with the linked example

```
$ db2 "create table emoji(string_with_emjoi varchar(32))"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 "insert into emoji values 'foobar'" 
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 "select string_with_emjoi, hex(string_with_emjoi) string_with_emjoi_hex from emoji"

STRING_WITH_EMJOI                STRING_WITH_EMJOI_HEX                                           
-------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
foobar                          666F6FF09D8C86626172
```

Code point for emjoi is stored with 4 bytes (0xF09D8C86). If you have an issue displaying the emoji after retrieval you need to dig a bit deeper and see what is the actual value returned by the database - problem very well might be in the application itself.